# Is there some way to make Edittext scroll in normal, smooth mode

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, smoothing

Without using scrollview, because if i use it, i will have some problem with cursor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested..

currently I'm achieving this with AsyncTask and some code that starts scrolling when user makes small finger flip for < 0.3 seconds.